# How to check that fifth and sixth characters are a specific two-digit number?

Tags: php, regex

I would like to validate phone numbers. The only valid phone numbers start like this:
+36 20 | +36 30 | +36 31 | +36 70

My code looks like this, but now you can enter +36 21 or +36 71 which I would like to avoid. How can I check for a two digit number? Like 70 or 30.

```
$phone = '+36 70 123 4567';

if ( preg_match( '|^\+36 [237][01] [1-9][0-9]{2} [0-9]{2}[0-9]{2}$|', $phone ) ) { 
    echo 'phone number is good';
}
```

Comment: Use alternations, `(?:[237]0|31)` instead of `[237][01]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want some very specific numbers:

```
/^\+36(20|30|31).../
```

Using set notation (`[237][01]`) will open up way too many other possibilities as you've observed.

Answer (score 1):

You may use *non-capturing groups* to specify the values you need to allow:

```
^\+36 (?:[237]0|31) [1-9][0-9]{2} [0-9]{4}$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VgFskv/2)

The `[237][01]` (two consecutive *character classes*) matches `2` or `3` or `7` followed with `0` or `1`, while `(?:[237]0|31)` matches either `2`, `3`, `7` and then `0`, or `31` char sequence.

The whole pattern matches:

- `^` - start of stirng
- `+36`   - `+36` and a space
- `(?:[237]0|31)` - see description above
- - space
- `[1-9]` - a character class matching a single digit rom `1` to `9` (excludes `0`)
- `[0-9]{2}` - any 2 ASCII digits (from `0` to `9`)
- - space
- `[0-9]{4}` - 4 digits
- `$` - end of string.

Note that instead of literal spaces, you may use `\s` that matches any whitespace, and to match 1 or 0 occurrences (if the whitespace is optional) you may add `?` (or `*` to match 0+ occurrences) after  `\s` - `\s?` / `\s*`.

Comment: Wow! Thanks! I've used a different solution, but your detailed description helped a lot to understand what's going on :)

Comment: @CsordásGergő Well, upvoting is enough to say thanks :) If you found another answer working best for you it is OK.

Answer (score 1):

```
$re = '/\+36\s(20|30|31|70)\s.*/';
$str = '+36 20 4145654';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

var_dump($matches);
```

Here I used `\s` to match all whitespace characters. Of course you can also use space character only like this:

```
$re = '/\+36 (20|30|31|70) .*/';
```